# How to load Google's TFLite model for smartreply into the python interpreter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, bazel

I am trying to load the `smartreply.tflite` model into the python interpreter so I can use that to generate replies based on a question. The model uses 3 custom operations(`predict`, `normalize` and `extract_features`).

I am successfully able to load the three operations into the interpreter, however, when I try to load the model into the interpreter, it gives me an error telling me that the operation `Normalize` wasn't found.

I expect to get no errors when I load the tflite model.

I suspect that when I try to load the model, it only looks for the needed operations in a built-in directory.

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue trying to load the `smartreply.tflite` into swift... were you able to solve this?